# How do I get credentials on AWS? Must I use AWS Cognito SDK or AWS SDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I'm building a rich front-end client for AWS S3 using the AWS SDK. It works fine to hard code IAM credentials into the AWS SDK configuration, but I would like to provision access to the end user via AWS Cognito.

How can I get credentials for the users I've created in my Cognito user pool?

The AWS documentation is very unclear. There are examples I've seen using the AWS SDK and examples I've seen saying you need to have a different AWS Cognito SDK. Which documentation article is correct?

*For this particular project I'm **NOT** wanting to use third-party federated identities at all.*

---

**UPDATE 2:**

The AWS Cognito SDK has been merged into a new library called AWS Amplify.
https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify

**UPDATE 1:**

The problem is two-fold. Understanding the terminology and properly setting up Cognito is the first part. Thanks to Bruce0 for getting me up and running there. The second part is the javascript part. It turns out that you need two separate libraries to authenticate Cognito users purely from javascript.

This is the solution I came up with. If it looks foreign to you, make sure that you've studied up on your es6 with promises/async/await. To run it in node you just need to preprocess it using babel, preset es2015, preset stage-2, and the babel-transform-runtime plugin. If you want to run it in the browser you'll probably need to use the babel-loader with webpack (which is notoriously complicated to set up, just a forewarning).

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk/global';
import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';
import {
  AuthenticationDetails,
  CognitoUser,
  CognitoUserPool,
} from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

const REGION = 'some-string-value';
const USER_POOL_ID = 'some-string-value';
const IDENTITY_POOL_ID = 'some-string-value';
const APP_CLIENT_ID = 'some-string-value';
const POOL_KEY = `cognito-idp.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/${USER_POOL_ID}`;

let Username = 'some-string-value';
let Password = 'some-string-value';

let authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
  Username,
  Password
});

let userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
  UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID,
  ClientId: APP_CLIENT_ID
});

let cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
  Username,
  Pool: userPool
});

let skateboards = {
  mfaRequired(codeDeliveryDetails) {
    let mfaCode = prompt('MFA code is required!');

    cognitoUser.sendMFACode(mfaCode, mfaRequired);
  },
  newPasswordRequired(userAttributes, requiredAttributes) {
    delete userAttributes.email_verified; // it's returned but not valid to submit

    let newPassword = prompt('A new password is required!');

    cognitoUser.completeNewPasswordChallenge(newPassword, userAttributes, newPasswordRequired);
  }
};

let updateAWSCreds = (jwtToken) => {
  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    Logins: {
      [POOL_KEY]: jwtToken
    }
  });
};

let authenticateCognitoUser = async ({mfaRequired, newPasswordRequired} = skateboards) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess(result) {
        let jwtToken = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
        updateAWSCreds(jwtToken);
        resolve();
      },
      onFailure(err) {
        reject(err);
      },
      mfaRequired,
      newPasswordRequired
    });
  });
};

let doSomethingInS3ForExample = async () => {
  await authenticateCognitoUser();

  // now do your stuff
};

doSomethingInS3ForExample();
```

https://gist.github.com/sbussard/7344c6e1f56051da0758d1403a4343b1

Comment: I would not do too much with the aws sdk on the client since it'd required to make the AWS secret key available on the client. I'd either go with cognito, or aws sdk on the backend and use presigned requests on the client

Comment: The only way to get credentials in Cognito is to create a Federated Identity Pool.  The cognitoIdentity and credentialsProvider methods ARE the way you get credentials.  You do not have to Federate identities to use the Federated identity Pool but you DO need to have an identityId (and those only exist in the pool).  So you will have a cognitoUserPool as the only authentication provider in the Federated Identity Pool (nothing will be federated) and IAM roles are provided (usually Authenticated and Unauthenticated) by that identity pool (but you can have more roles)

Comment: @Bruce0 indeed! that is what I'm experiencing so far. Cognito seems truly revolutionary. Your help is greatly appreciated, and will no-doubt positively affect millions of people in the coming months, not including whitespace ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to get credentials in Cognito is to create a Federated Identity Pool. The cognitoIdentity and credentialsProvider methods ARE the way you get credentials.

You do not have to Federate identities to use the Federated identity Pool but you DO need to have an identityId (and those only exist in the pool) in order to get credentials.

So you will have a cognitoUserPool as the only authentication provider in the Federated Identity Pool (nothing will be federated) and IAM roles are provided (usually Authenticated and Unauthenticated) by that identity pool (but you can have more roles).

Here is a link to a powerpoint explaining some of the basic confusing aspects of Cognito, I hope that helps.  [Cognito outline](https://github.com/BruceBuckland/SignIn-awsmhh/blob/master/cognito%20diagram.pdf)

Lastly I would recommend that you start your implementation using the AWS Mobile Hub (At least as an example), as opposed to using the IOS SDK.  The Mobile Hub is a thin wrapper but does a lot of the heaving lifting and is nicely architected.

Comment: So that looks pretty awesome. It looks like the Mobile hub has some nice features for getting set up. It doesn't have anything for browser / javascript though. Your answer is still is super helpful to me, so I'll probably mark it as correct when I get it connected, maybe with an edit to add the browser-specific piece. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You are correct, the mobile hub does not do Javascript.  But it will get your IAM roles set up correctly, and help you get the identity pool and user pool set up, and do IAM policies for the stuff you want to access, and unless you are used to all that stuff, it gets a bit elaborate.  Good luck, and thanks

Answer (score 1):

This works for me below, I set up cognito to create a identity pool, and the IAM to add the profile to the user (i followed this link exactly : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html)

```
import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3'
import AWS from 'aws-sdk/global'

AWS.config.update({
  region: process.env.AZ_REGION,
  credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'XXX'
  })
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
params: {Bucket: process.env.AZ_BUCKETNAME},
      });
```

I only wish we didn't need to import the  aws-sdk/global it itself is 206k unminified. Thats a lot to throw down to the user.